# PyTorch - Element-wise signed min/max?

Tags: python, pytorch, min, sign, absolute-value

I may be missing something obvious, but I can't find a way to compute this.

Given two tensors, I want to keep the minimum elements in each one of them as well as the sign.

I thought about

```
sign_x = torch.sign(x)
sign_y = torch.sign(y)
min = torch.min(torch.abs(x), torch.abs(y))
```

in order to eventually multiply the signs with the obtained minimums, but then I have no method to multiply the correct sign to each element that was kept and must choose one of the two tensors.

Comment: Which sign do you want to end up with if `x` is negative and `y` is positive, but they have the same absolute value?

Comment: Since they're floats I find that unlikely to happen, but a coin flip is probably the solution in that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to do it. Multiply `torch.sign(x)` and `torch.sign(y)` by a tensor of booleans representing whether `x` or `y` is the result of the `min` calculation. Then take the logical or (`|`) of the two resulting tensors to combine them, and multiply that by the `min` calculation.

```
mins = torch.min(torch.abs(x), torch.abs(y))

xSigns = (mins == torch.abs(x)) * torch.sign(x)
ySigns = (mins == torch.abs(y)) * torch.sign(y)
finalSigns = xSigns.int() | ySigns.int()

result = mins * finalSigns
```

If `x` and `y` have the same absolute value for a certain element, in the code above the sign of `x` takes precedence. For `y` to take precedence, swap the order and use `finalSigns = ySigns.int() | xSigns.int()` instead.

Comment: Thank you, I think this works! I didn't know you could do this with tensors.